# Change port for selenium tests

Tags: java, selenium, security, testing, owasp

Im trying to set up selenium tests using zap, the webdriver should be firefox and the port 8080. But when it opens up the port is always a different number.
This is the test below, I dont know how o open the browser under the port 8080 anfd firefox browser, the browser does actually open but nothing appears.

```
public class Sport {
WebDriver driver;
final static String BASE_URL = "https://web-test.com/";
final static String USERNAME = "test@hotmail.com";
final static String PASSWORD = "tables";

public Sport(WebDriver driver) {


    this.driver = driver;
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void login()throws Exception {
    driver.get(BASE_URL);
    Header header = new Header();
    header.guest_select_login();
    Pages.Login login = new Pages.Login();

    login.login_with_empty_fields();

    login.login_with_invalid_email();

    login.email_or_password_incorrect();


    login.login_open_and_close();
}
```

The Client zap api is working and starting it seems but the browser doesnt seem to open correctly to port 8080

```
public class ZapScanTest  {
static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(ZapScanTest.class.getName());
private final static String ZAP_PROXYHOST = "127.0.0.1";
private final static int ZAP_PROXYPORT = 8080;
private final static String ZAP_APIKEY = null;

// Change this to the appropriate driver for the OS, alternatives in the 
drivers directory
private final static String FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH = "drivers/geckodriver.exe";
private final static String MEDIUM = "MEDIUM";
private final static String HIGH = "HIGH";
private ScanningProxy zapScanner;
private Spider zapSpider;
private WebDriver driver;
private Sportdec myApp;
private final static String[] policyNames = {"directory-browsing","cross- 
site-scripting","sql-injection","path-traversal","remote-file- 
inclusion","server-side-include",
"script-active-scan-rules","server-side-code-injection","external- 
redirect","crlf-injection"};
int currentScanID;


@Before
public void setup() {
    zapScanner = new ZAProxyScanner(ZAP_PROXYHOST,ZAP_PROXYPORT,ZAP_APIKEY);
    zapScanner.clear(); //Start a new session
    zapSpider = (Spider)zapScanner;
    log.info("Created client to ZAP API");
    driver = DriverFactory.createProxyDriver ("firefox",createZapProxyConfigurationForWebDriver(), FIREFOX_DRIVER_PATH);

    myApp = new Sportdec(driver);
    //myApp.registerUser(); 
}

@After
public void after() {
    driver.quit();
}

@Test
public void testSecurityVulnerabilitiesBeforeLogin()throws Exception  {
    myApp.login();
    log.info("Spidering...");
    spiderWithZap();
    log.info("Spider done.");

    setAlertAndAttackStrength();
    zapScanner.setEnablePassiveScan(true);
    scanWithZap();

    List<Alert> alerts = filterAlerts(zapScanner.getAlerts());
    logAlerts(alerts);
    assertThat(alerts.size(), equalTo(0));
}
```

Comment: You need to add the port to the url. www.address.com:8080/somefolder/somepage.html

Comment: Ok so i ran https://web-game-stage.sport.com:8080/ but still got https://web-game-stage.sportdec.com:8080/ but got org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: